# Limit user input to 3 integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to change the requirement to put in digits to only allow three digits.

```
shootnum = None
while True:
    try:
        shootnum = int(input("Enter today's shoot number > "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number, please try again.")
```

What do I need to change to adapt the ValueError ?

Comment: Just check `if 100 <= shootnum <= 999`

Comment: Raise a `ValueError` if the integer does not fit your requirements!

Comment: Compare against the regex `^\d{3}$` and if it fails, raise a `ValueError`  (the regex might be improved)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why dont you just simply limit the input to 3 digits:

```
shootnum = int(input("Enter today's shoot number > ")[:3])
print(shootnum)
```

If you have issues with numbers beginning with `0` then you can do the following instead:

```
shootnum = (int(input("Enter today's shoot number > ")))
shootnum = (str(shootnum))
shootnum = int(shootnum[:3])
print((shootnum))
```

Comment: It's  not really clear to the user you truncate his response,  better to raise an error

Comment: I'm adding that option to my answer

Comment: In the meantime

Comment: It also fails if the user inputs `-12`, for example.

Comment: This works but does not allow an input such as 015 which is what I use to keep everything looking neat. As shoot days can go from 001 to 325 ?

Comment: True but I only answered specifically to what OP asked,'Limit user input to 3 integers'.

Comment: @Achilles Not really. 001 is three integers. So is 015 or 020. You simply limited the input to three _characters_.

Answer (score 0):

Just say:

```
if x <= 999 and x >= 100:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No.")
```

Comment: Or the more idiomatic `if 100 <= x <= 999:`

Answer (score 0):

1 regular expression (inspired by Maarten Fabré)

```
import re

while True:
    try:
        shoot = raw_input("Enter today's shoot number > ") # I use python 2.7
        shootnum = int(shoot)
        if not re.match(r'\d{3}$', shoot):
            raise ValueError # can be caught by except
        print shootnum
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number, please try again.")
```

2 just check whether shoot is a three digits

```
while True:
    try:
        shoot = raw_input("Enter today's shoot number > ") # I use python 2.7
        shootnum = int(shoot)
        if len(shoot) != 3 or shoot[0] == '-':
             raise ValueError # can be caught by except
        print shootnum
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number, please try again.")
```

results are below

```
Enter today's shoot number > qwer
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > -12
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > 123
123
Enter today's shoot number > 1222
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > 012
12
Enter today's shoot number > 0122
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > 0
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > 00
Invalid number, please try again.
Enter today's shoot number > 000
0
Enter today's shoot number > 0000
Invalid number, please try again.
```

Comment: But what if I want to allow numbers such as 001 all the way up to 999 ?

Comment: @JonathanPetts So three digits can mean numbers, like 001?